# Unable to map data from JPA query to model class

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT vip, instance FROM REPORT", nativeQuery = true)
    List<VipINFO> findAllVIPS ();
```

I have this method in repository class, I want to map this data to List.

```
public class VIPInfo
{
    private String vip;

    private String instance;
}
```

I am getting this error when calling findAllVIPS method.

No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.sap.ariba.security.emc.model.HanaVIPInfo]

Answer (score 1):

You can’t rely on Spring Data JPA’s automatic mapping feature when using a native query

The easiest way to do it is using interface-based DTO.

```
public interface VIPInfo {
    String getVip();
    String getInstance();
}
```

If you still want to use class-based DTO then you must define and reference a `@NamedNativeQuery` with an `@SqlResultSetMapping`.

Refer to this [article](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/)